# Latest Module - get users and orders

Tags: php, opencart

I had one ideia in opencart *but I don't know how* can I **put number of all registered users**, **number of all orders**, **number of all completed orders**, and the **number of all products** in `Latest Module`, can anyone help me how to do it? I searched a lot before come here but I didn't find anything :(

Example:

We have: **2402** members

Number of orders: **24**

Completed orders: **2**

We have: **10** products

Comment: The heck are you trying to ask? Edit your question and ask it properly,i didnt understand anything from this.

Comment: you will find some reports (in the admin area) that display total # of users, total # of orders ..., just see how these reports are made, give a try and if you have a problem post it here

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps.

1. Make a new module.
2. Copy the dashboard report models into your new model.
3. Fetch your desired result and display it into your new module.

That's simple.

Comment: but I want to add this to **latest module**

Comment: You can add these models to pre-existing latest module and display the result in it.

Just a hint.

Try calling `$data['customer'] = $this->load->controller('dashboard/customer');` into your module/latest.php controller and then echo $data['customer'] in your controller or $customer into your tpl file.